# NullpointerException on getting the value from share preference from service where i am putting value into it in Activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I am trying to access the `sharepreference` value from an activity to one service but it is throwing `NullPointerException`, I tried a lot but still I am getting the same problem, I searched many question related with this and tried their ways to solve but it didnt worked. It will be great of you if you please guide me on this. Thanks in Advance,

Here is the code

I have defined SharePreferences in my service class as

```
SharedPreferences preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
Editor editor=preferences.edit();
```

and than I am trying to put value in it in My Activity as

```
foregroundService.editor.putString(foregroundService.com, data.getComponent().toString());
foregroundService.editor.commit();
```

and again going back in service class to access the value as

```
preferences.getString(com, "not available");
```

Please Help, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add the value in the activity using:

```
SharedPreferences preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
Editor editor=preferences.edit(); 
editor.putString(foregroundService.com, data.getComponent().toString());
editor.commit();
```

it's always the same preferences, as you are using the default one

Answer (score 0):

Look at the line you have put the name as `foregroundService.com`

```
foregroundService.editor.putString(foregroundService.com, data.getComponent().toString());
```

and you are trying to get as

```
preferences.getString(com, "not available");
```

The name must be same for both put and get.

change it to `preferences.getString(foregroundService.com, "not available");` 
Try it ..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both the Activity and Service are using the same package and therefore share the same Context, I think it has something to do with the fact that inside the Service, Context = null due to the fact that getApplicationContext() is not available.

The solution is:

```
SharedPreferences preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

If context isn't available inside your service you'll need to pass it in to your Service's onCreate function when you instantiate the service.

Comment: Hi @Mat, your answer is very help full to understand it. I tried to pass context in getDefaultSharedPreferences than that "service class is not initiating "error is coming , what should i do now please help